# ASP.Net MVC 4 -> Loading symbols takes 25s

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a new MVC4 application in Visual Studio 2012.

Each time I run this (F5) it takes about 25s for all symbols to load.

Is it normal it takes this long each time?
(I have a recent/fast laptop)

I already removed some libraries I don't need.

Choosing between build/release doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Debugging is slow. How is the speed when you start without debugging?

Comment: You're right. Starting with ctrl-F5 is fast. Still strange that it is this slow with debugging.

Comment: Its not that strange really. Debugging information introduces a huge overhead into your application, which is why you should disable it when deploying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A co-worker of mine has this very same issue.  In his case at least, as unrelated as it may seem, it turned out to be his virus scanner.  Obviously disabling the virus scanner is not an option, but he was able to add folder-level exclusions to his virus scanner and he did so with the folders that contained the solutions he was working with.  From what I understand, this remedied the issues he was seeing.

Comment: Disabling symantec doesn't improve speed here, but I'll try on a laptop without virus scanner.

Comment: I tried the same project on a different laptop without antivirus. Here it starts very fast! (with debugging)

Comment: Yes, I believe my co-worker that had the issue was dealing with Symantec as well, and I think disabling didn't work either.  He either uninstalled and installed a different solution or found where he could add folder-level exclusions.  Maybe try Microsoft Security Essentials?  

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/security-essentials-download

Comment: disabling McAfee didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

Try uncheck this option:

Tools\Options\Debugging\General\Enable source server support